# Objective-C - Mocking a segmented control using OCMock?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing, mocking, ocmock

I am trying to mockj a segmented control and I am getting crashes, any suggestions?

```
NSInteger selectedSegment = 2;
id segmentedControlMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[UISegmentedControl class]];
[[[segmentedControlMock stub] andReturn:OCMOCK_VALUE(selectedSegment)] selectedSegmentIndex];
```

I get a crash as soon as i call selectedSegmentIndex on my mock object:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Expected invocation with object return type.'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `andReturnValue:`

```
NSInteger selectedSegment = 2;
id segmentedControlMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[UISegmentedControl class]];
[[[segmentedControlMock stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(selectedSegment)] selectedSegmentIndex];
```